# How do I send a variable from one function to another function?

Tags: python, django

Here is an example of a function that I want to be able to pass one variable to the other.

```
def foo(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        unique_id = request.POST.get('per_id','')
        baz = get_object_or_404(Name, pk=unique_id)
        return render(request, 'details/guy.html', {'baz': baz})
    return render(request, 'details/person.html')

def bar(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        baz = get_object_or_404(Name, pk=unique_id)
        return render(request, 'details/guy.html', {'baz': baz})
    return render(request, 'details/guy.html')
```

The problem is this:

```
local variable 'unique_id' referenced before assignment
```

So, how do I get this variable to feed from the foo(request) function to the bar(request) function?

I know I can use cPickle, but the amount of traffic this website will be getting will almost certainly cause the cPickle object to be mixed up with another person.

Comment: Why not simply stick it in their session

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting from foo to bar. Are you doing a redirect? Why can't you put the ID into the URL, like you would with any other request?

Comment: What do you mean stick it in their session? Are you talking about a user being logged in?

Comment: and to Daniel, I am doing a redirect. I had to edit the original post (sorry). I don't know how to send it through the URL. I'm still new to Django

Comment: Where is your redirect? Currently you are not redirecting at all.

Comment: I updated the original post to show the redirect in the foo function

Comment: Can you please explain, why you cannot get `unique_id` the same way as in the first view function, i.e. via `request.POST.get('unique_id')`?

Comment: It is not a redirect, you are just rendering your output with a different template. You don't call the view `bar` at all. Read docs about `return redirect(...)` instead.

Comment: The people being registered on the site are being assigned a unique ID. In order to get into the profile page you need their unique ID and a password (because the website respects their anonymity due to the nature of what is being disclosed). The unique ID gets put into a form as well as the password which takes you to a page where you can donate money towards their cause... in which case I need to unique ID because it is the pk.

Comment: Then @tilaprimera answer is correct. In general, if `unique_id` needs to be available across requests by the same client (= session). and this calls for session management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session Variable should be used sparsely.

```
def foo(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        unique_id = request.POST.get('per_id','')
        request.session["unique_id"] = unique_id
        baz = get_object_or_404(Name, pk=unique_id)
        return render(request, 'details/guy.html', {'baz': baz})
    return render(request, 'details/person.html')

def bar(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        baz = get_object_or_404(Name, pk=request.session["unique_id"])
        del request.session["unique_id"]
        return render(request, 'details/guy.html', {'baz': baz})
    return render(request, 'details/guy.html')
```

I would not recommend but one can use global variable too.

```
unique_id = None

def foo(request):
    global unique_id
    unique_id = 10

def bar(request):
    print unique_id
```